# Intellij Idea annoying window dialog after class creation

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have installed IntelliJ Idea Community (after a long time using Android Studio).

I created a simply Gradle Java project to make some RxJava exercises from a course I'm taking.

But there is something different... After I create a new class from `file/new class` this dialog is shown:

[image]

And from what I realized this window is useless because as you can see I typed 'public' in the appropriate field, however my class was created as package-private:

[image]

I'm using the latest stable version of IntelliJ Idea Community:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6
Build #IC-172.4574.11, built on November 13, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
```

Comment: This dialog is not native IDEA new 'Java Class' dialog. Do you use 3rd plugins? How exactly did you invoke new 'Java Class' action? Have you migrated settings from AndroidStudio?

Comment: I 've invoked from the traditional way: File/New/Java Class. Yes, I imported the settings saved by Android Studio. I'm pretty sure that it was the problem.. I'm looking for a way to make this that dialog disappears without discard the settings I've imported if possible.

Comment: look up this page, it solve my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244397/intellij-new-java-class-opening-a-different-dialog-than-usual