# Android Studio not showing full sized "new java class" dialog

Tags: android-studio

Can anyone tell me how to change the settings in my android studio to allow it to show full sized "create new class" dialog as opposed to the mini view it is showing now?

Comment: Try using the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244397/intellij-new-java-class-opening-a-different-dialog-than-usual